# get two json array values in one adapter .One json array values show in list

Tags: java, android

I'm getting two json arrays from server response .I'm able to set it in model class but I don't know where I'm doing mistake because these values are not visible in list .Please check my code and tell me , my mistake.

My method in activity class

```
 private void pastappointments() {


    final String requestBody = "'{\"UtcTimeOffset\":\"330\",\"DocId\":\"1079\"}'";

    Log.e(TAG, "Login :: " + requestBody);
    NetworkManager.getInstance(this).makeNetworkRequestForJSON(1, Request.Method.POST, Common.BASE_URL + "/PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule", null, requestBody
            , null,
            new NetworkResponseListenerJSONObject() {
                @Override
                public void onDataReceived(int requestCode, Object data) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "requestCode :: " + requestCode);
                    Log.e(TAG, "data :: " + data);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response : " + data.toString());

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                        JSONObject ResponseJsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Response");
                        int ResponseCode = ResponseJsonObject1.getInt("ResponseCode");
                        String ResponseText = ResponseJsonObject1.getString("ResponseText");


                        if (ResponseCode == 1) {
                            JSONArray arrDetail = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detail");

                            for(int i = 0; i < arrDetail.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jSlot = arrDetail.getJSONObject(i);

                                PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule slotInfo = new PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule();

                                slotInfo.BlockId = jSlot.getString("BlockId");
                                slotInfo.DateOfSlot = jSlot.getString("DateOfSlot");
                                slotInfo.fkScheduledId = jSlot.getInt("fkScheduledId");
                                slotInfo.fkTimeId= jSlot.getString("fkTimeId");


                                slotInfo.AvailableTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();
                                JSONArray arrAvailableTimeSlots = jsonObject.getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
                                for(int j = 0; j < arrAvailableTimeSlots.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jAvailableTimeSlot = arrAvailableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(j);

                                    AvailableTimeSlots availableTimeSlot = new AvailableTimeSlots();
                                    availableTimeSlot.timeOfSlot = jAvailableTimeSlot.getString("TimeOfSlot");

                                    slotInfo.AvailableTimeSlots.add(availableTimeSlot);
                                }

                                // then GetBlockedTimings
                                slotInfo.GetBlockedTimings = new ArrayList<>();
                                JSONArray arrGetBlockedTimings = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings");
                                for(int k = 0; k < arrGetBlockedTimings.length(); k++) {
                                    JSONObject jGetBlockedTiming = arrAvailableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(k);

                                    GetBlockedTimings getBlockedTiming = new GetBlockedTimings();
                                    getBlockedTiming.blockId = jGetBlockedTiming.getInt("fkTimeId_block");

                                    slotInfo.GetBlockedTimings.add(getBlockedTiming);

                                }

                                slotInfos.add(slotInfo);
                            }

                        }
                        pastAppointmentsAdapter = new PastAppointmentAdapter(Mainactivity3.this, slotInfos);
                        rv_get_doctor_schedule.setAdapter(pastAppointmentsAdapter);

                    }

                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

//                        pastAppointmentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

```
                @Override
                public void onDataFailed(int requestCode, VolleyError error) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "requestCode :: " + requestCode);
                    Log.e(TAG, "data :: " + error);

                    String json = null;
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                        switch (response.statusCode) {
                            case 400:
                                json = new String(response.data);
                                json = trimMessage(json, "error_description");
                                if (json != null) displayMessage(json);
                                break;
                        }
                        //Additional cases
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

```html
 My Adapter class code
public class PastAppointmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PastAppointmentsViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "UpcomingAppoinmentsListAdapter";
    private ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> pastAppointmentlist;
    private ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> getBlockedTimings;
    private List<GetBlockedTimings> getblocklist;
    private ArrayList<PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule> PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule;
    Activity context;
  
    String fkscheduleid, DateofSlot;
    int value_block;
    
    int Doc_Id, fk_id, slot_id;
    String timeofslot;
   
    String tsId;
    String time = "";
    PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule c = null;
   
int timeslot_id_value;
    

   public PastAppointmentAdapter(Mainactivity3 context, ArrayList<PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule> postDoctorGetDoctorSchedulepojo) {
       this.context = context;
       this.PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule = postDoctorGetDoctorSchedulepojo;

   }

    @Override
    public PastAppointmentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_get_doctor_schedule, parent, false);
        return new PastAppointmentsViewHolder(v);
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PastAppointmentsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule c = PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule.get(position);


        timeofslot=c.AvailableTimeSlots.get(position).getTimeOfSlot(); // I want to get "TimeOfSlot" values 
        // and "fkTimeId_block" which I'm adding in my main activity code
        holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setText(timeofslot);
        fk_id = c.GetBlockedTimings.get(position).getFkTimeId();
        value_block=fk_id;
        Log.e("DateofSlot11122", String.valueOf(fk_id));



       String fk_value= String.valueOf(fk_id);

       if(timeofslot==fk_value){
           holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       }

      holder.ll_row_item_get_doctor_schedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.btn_block1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        holder.btn_block1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));



                final Dialog lDialog = new Dialog(context);
                lDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                lDialog.setCancelable(false);
                lDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                lDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(.7f);
                lDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    lDialog.getWindow().setElevation(4);
                }

                lDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_no_yes);
                TextView tv_titiel = (TextView) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_titiel);
                TextView textMsg = (TextView) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_msgs);
                Button btnno = (Button) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_no_btn);
                Button btnyes = (Button) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_yes_btn);
                btnno.setTransformationMethod(null);
                btnyes.setTransformationMethod(null);
                tv_titiel.setText("Schedule");
                textMsg.setText("Are you sure you want to block this slot?");
                btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lDialog.dismiss();
                        holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    }
                });
                btnyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                        timeslot_id_value=c.AvailableTimeSlots.get(position).getTimeSlotId();
                        fkscheduleid=c.getScheduleId();
                        DateofSlot=c.getDateOfSlot();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"click_value"+timeslot_id_value + " " + fkscheduleid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  lDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                lDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule.size();

    }


    /*slot blocking*/

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")

    public String trimMessage(String json, String key) {
        String trimmedString = null;

        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return trimmedString;
    }

    //Somewhere that has access to a context
    public void displayMessage(String toastString) {
        Toast.makeText(context, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```html
public class PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule
{
    public String fkTimeId;

    public String ScheduleId;

    public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> AvailableTimeSlots;

    public String BlockId;

    public int fkScheduledId;

    public Boolean IsDeleted;

    //public ArrayList<ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings>> GetBlockedTimings=new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> GetBlockedTimings;

    public String DateOfSlot;

    public String utcDateOfSlot;

    public String getFkTimeId ()
    {
        return fkTimeId;
    }

    public void setFkTimeId (String fkTimeId)
    {
        this.fkTimeId = fkTimeId;
    }

    public String getScheduleId ()
    {
        return ScheduleId;
    }

    public void setScheduleId (String ScheduleId)
    {
        this.ScheduleId = ScheduleId;
    }

    public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> getAvailableTimeSlots ()
    {
        return AvailableTimeSlots;
    }

    public void setAvailableTimeSlots (ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> AvailableTimeSlots)
    {
        this.AvailableTimeSlots = AvailableTimeSlots;
    }

    public String getBlockId ()
    {
        return BlockId;
    }

    public void setBlockId (String BlockId)
    {
        this.BlockId = BlockId;
    }

    public int getFkScheduledId ()
    {
        return fkScheduledId;
    }

    public void setFkScheduledId (int fkScheduledId)
    {
        this.fkScheduledId = fkScheduledId;
    }

    public Boolean getIsDeleted ()
    {
        return IsDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted (Boolean IsDeleted)
    {
        this.IsDeleted = IsDeleted;
    }

//    public List<ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings>> getGetBlockedTimings ()
//    {
//        return GetBlockedTimings;
//    }

    public ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> getGetBlockedTimings ()
    {
        return GetBlockedTimings;
    }

//    public void setGetBlockedTimings (ArrayList<ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings>> GetBlockedTimings)
//    {
//        this.GetBlockedTimings = GetBlockedTimings;
//    }

    public void setGetBlockedTimings (ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> GetBlockedTimings)
    {
        this.GetBlockedTimings = GetBlockedTimings;
    }

    public String getDateOfSlot ()
    {
        return DateOfSlot;
    }

    public void setDateOfSlot (String DateOfSlot)
    {
        this.DateOfSlot = DateOfSlot;
    }

    public String getUtcDateOfSlot ()
    {
        return utcDateOfSlot;
    }

    public void setUtcDateOfSlot (String utcDateOfSlot)
    {
        this.utcDateOfSlot = utcDateOfSlot;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [fkTimeId = "+fkTimeId+", ScheduleId = "+ScheduleId+", AvailableTimeSlots = "+AvailableTimeSlots+", BlockId = "+BlockId+", fkScheduledId = "+fkScheduledId+", IsDeleted = "+IsDeleted+", GetBlockedTimings = "+GetBlockedTimings+", DateOfSlot = "+DateOfSlot+", utcDateOfSlot = "+utcDateOfSlot+"]";
    }



    /*block time modal*/
    public class GetBlockedTimings {


        public int blockId;
        public int fkTimeId;
        public Boolean isDeleted;
        public String BlockDateOfSlot;
        public int fkScheduledId;
        public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> availableTimeSlots;
        public ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> GetBlockedTimings;



        public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> getAvailableTimeSlots() {
            return availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public void setAvailableTimeSlots(ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> availableTimeSlots) {
            this.availableTimeSlots = availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> getGetBlockedTimings() {
            return GetBlockedTimings;
        }

        public void setGetBlockedTimings(ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> getBlockedTimings) {
            GetBlockedTimings = getBlockedTimings;
        }

        public String getBlockDateOfSlot() {
            return BlockDateOfSlot;
        }

        public void setBlockDateOfSlot(String blockDateOfSlot) {
            BlockDateOfSlot = blockDateOfSlot;
        }

        public int getBlockId() {
            return blockId;
        }

        public void setBlockId(int blockId) {
            this.blockId = blockId;
        }

        public int getFkTimeId() {
            return fkTimeId;
        }

        public void setFkTimeId(int fkTimeId) {
            this.fkTimeId = fkTimeId;
        }

        public Boolean getDeleted() {
            return isDeleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
            isDeleted = deleted;
        }

        public int getFkScheduledId() {
            return fkScheduledId;
        }

        public void setFkScheduledId(int fkScheduledId) {
            this.fkScheduledId = fkScheduledId;
        }

    }

    /*getavaliableslots*/
    public class AvailableTimeSlots  {

        public int timeSlotId;
        public String timeOfSlot;
        public String timeofSlotDateTime;

        public int getTimeSlotId() {
            return timeSlotId;
        }

        public void setTimeSlotId(int timeSlotId) {
            this.timeSlotId = timeSlotId;
        }

        public String getTimeOfSlot() {
            return timeOfSlot;
        }

        public void setTimeOfSlot(String timeOfSlot) {
            this.timeOfSlot = timeOfSlot;
        }

        public String getTimeofSlotDateTime() {
            return timeofSlotDateTime;
        }

        public void setTimeofSlotDateTime(String timeofSlotDateTime) {
            this.timeofSlotDateTime = timeofSlotDateTime;
        }


    }
}
```

I want to learn it by json and volley not by GSON .And please reply on it don't unlike it . If any example which is according to my requirement then also share. I have post my same question but till now no valid reply I got .It's humble request please help me here. Below I'm providing my server response also.

Server response :-

```html
{
        "Response": {
            "ResponseCode": 1,
            "ResponseText": "Success"
        },
        "Detail": [
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "08/31/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 42,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:15 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T12:15:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4203,
                "GetBlockedTimings": [
                    {
                        "DateOfSlot": "8/31/2018 12:00:00 AM",
                        "AvailableTimeSlots": null,
                        "ScheduleId": 0,
                        "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                        "BlockId": 1831,
                        "fkTimeId": 42,
                        "IsDeleted": false,
                        "fkScheduledId": 4203,
                        "utcDateOfSlot": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "09/1/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 112,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:00 AM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-01T00:00:00"
                    },

                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-01T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4204,
                "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "09/2/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 112,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:00 AM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-02T00:00:00"
                    },

                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-02T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4205,
                "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The response contains one json message not two. Why is that? If you want to parse two messages, then shouldn't there be 2 messages in this response?

Comment: plz check only array , I have issue with array .other things I'm able to handle. "AvailableTimeSlots" and  "GetBlockedTimings" jsonarray